# Google Maps Marker not working when zooming in or out?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently learning html, css and javascript and have been practising by building a landing page for a property development using bootstrap as the framework.

I'm a bit stuck with 2 things; I've added a custom map with a custom marker and whenever I zoom or move the map the marker seems to break and I can't work out why.

```
var image = {
      url: "img/nelsonsyardmap-pointer.svg", // url
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 69), // scaled size
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };

// Define the Lattitude and Longitude for the map location
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.9563142, -1.0760329);

 // Define the map marker characteristics
var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title:  'nelsonsmap'
        });
```

The link for the landing page is here

http://nelsonsyard.kinetik.agency/

Another thing I'm a bit stuck on is containing the images for the carousel so they proportionately scale. I know by declaring a height this doesn't work but if I don't the image's height becomes 100%. and is disorientated.

```
.carousel img { top: 0; left: 0; min-width: 100%; height: 450px; max-width: none;

}
```

Any advice would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: For the map marker icon, do you have access to the actual SVG file? If so, can you try adding `width="50px" height="69px"` to the `<svg>` tag and see what that does?

Comment: Yea I have the file :) but it's pulling in a link so there isn't an svg tag?

Comment: oh... I think I understand if I go into the actual svg code?

Comment: Yeah so go into the actual code where the SVG is being created, and add it onto the tag and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work with the icon, just the problem now is that when I zoom out on the map the marker isn't staying fixed to the location it's set to? I updated to the link

Comment: I seemed to have fixed it now thank you :)